# Strategy for error handling in Web Services

Tags: .net, web-services, architecture

We are working on a web application. All pages of this web application inherits from a base page, and we have a mechanism like

```
 this.Error += new EventHandler( Page_Error );

 private void Page_Error( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        Helper.LogError( this.Context );
    }
```

The above works pretty fine in all webpages.

Now we want to add couple of web services in our application. We also have a Base Service from which all other services will be inherited. However I am not able to setup a proper error loggin mechanism in webservice so far. Becase, I am not able to identify any event on which I could get the error info without putting Try Catch at respective service method calls.

Can someone suggest a strategy in such cases to have a commong generic error handling mechanism for web services.

Comment: Have a look at ASP.NET healthmonitoring. Works well, but has a difficult learning curve (not hard, just a bit weird).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by .net web service you mean WCF, then you can use FaultContracts etc as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733721.aspx).

There is also another way to handle it, which works for both WCF and asmx web services:

- Let all you Data Transfer Objects inherit from a "Error Information" object
- In each service, have a try catch
- In the catch, populate the Error Information with relevant data

Comment: Sorry I was not clear in my question but I actually meant traditional Web Service (.asmx)